# Sending a .json file with HttpServletResponse

Tags: servlets

I have a .json file that I would like to send to the <s>client</s> browser on a specific request inside the Servlet's `doGet()` method. My Java file IO is a little rusty so I'm having a little trouble figuring out what is the right way to do this. I figure it's something like:

```
File myfile = new File(mypath);
OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
out.print(new FileInputStream(myfile).read());
```

or something close-ish to that?

Comment: The Client is your `Front-end` application? or what?

Comment: yeah, just a webapp. Its really just what do I have to do to send a text file over a httpServletResponse. All the different readers and writers are a bit confusing having not used java in a few years

Comment: Why don't you just send text and set as a content-type text/plain?

Comment: Thats what I need help with. Just which readers and writers I need to use to accomplish exactly that. Its less a question of how to use the servletAPI as it is a question about basic file IO in java

Comment: Check if the answer helps now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set your HTTP Response content type to `text/plain` on your `HttpServletResponse` argument and write into response. Example would look like this:

```
package com.giorgi.controller;

import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/plain");
        List<String> file = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("c:\\path\to\your\file.json"));
        String data = file.stream().collect(Collectors.joining());
        response.getWriter().write(data);
    }
}
```

[setContentType(String type)](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/4.0/apidocs/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#setContentType-java.lang.String-) sets the content type of the response being sent to the client.

Comment: This is pretty good. My only concern is that I will be doing this with some potentially very large json files so I'm not sure if that will be an issue. Thats why I was thinking I should do it with streams and stuff